# Do logged hours with a Sport Pilot instructor count towards a private pilot certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

I've my Sport Pilot licence and I've got logged hours with a sport pilot instructor that isn't a private pilot instructor.

Can I use my logged instruction hours in order to upgrade to private pilot?

Answer (score 6):

No.  Sport pilot instructors are not authorized instructors with respect to private pilot certification.

See [61.109(a)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=8f2d411d76869d0aa65b96fa7fa5aa50&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1109&rgn=div8).

The FAA has issued a legal interpretation on the matter.  See the [Kern Ink interpretation](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2009/kern%20ink%20-%20(2009)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf)